# Docker-compose volume path dont change after edited

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was running a `docker-compose up -d` and I received the following error message:

```
Creating webserver ... 
Creating webserver ... error

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /home/root/SemanaOMnistack/backend/dhparam/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /home/root/SemanaOMnistack/backend/dhparam/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My volume path in `docker-compose.yml` was:

```
volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/root/SemanaOMnistack/backend/dhparam/
      o: bind
```

Thats ok, the path was wrong and I fixed It creating a new user and change the volume in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/leo/dev-maps/backend/dhparam/
      o: bind
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build` the path of volume specified in compose the same error message:

```
Creating webserver ... 
Creating webserver ... error

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /home/root/SemanaOMnistack/backend/dhparam/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /home/root/SemanaOMnistack/backend/dhparam/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_dhparam/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I tried everything like `docker system prune -a` and clear all cache of my Docker, and the same error message is showing !

**I just solve changing the name of volume for example to `dhparam2` so... the problem is not the path but the cache.**

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Please show your complete `docker-compose.yml`, at the very least your `webserver` service definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sometimes have a similar problem with mounting volumes in docker-compose and these are what work for me all the time:

```
docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans

docker-compose up -d -V --build --force-recreate
```

Please use `--help` to understand in more detail what each flag does. Hope this will work for you!

Comment: That solve my problem. The -v was needed to update path