# Docker-compose is throwing a volume path error while mounting even though the path is correct

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-volume

I'm trying to deploy a Node service with Nginx.

Following is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email <redacted> --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d dostoevsky.rest.com  -d www.dostoevsky.rest

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /root/dostoevskyrest/views/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY . .
RUN mkdir build && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm install && npm run build

FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/ ./

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Initially, there was a path error on line `device: /root/dostoevskyrest/views/` (fixed version), and I resolved it. However, the same error is still being thrown for the `webserver` service. I found a similar issue ([Docker-compose volume path dont change after edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031832/docker-compose-volume-path-dont-change-after-edited)) on SOF and tried the solution, but it still didn't work.

I'm deploying the service on a DigitalOcean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04) with Docker installed, by the way.

Following is the error:

```
ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/dostoevskyrest_web-root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /root/dostoevskyrest/views:/var/lib/docker/volumes/dostoevskyrest_web-root/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/dostoevskyrest_web-root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /root/dostoevskyrest/views:/var/lib/docker/volumes/dostoevskyrest_web-root/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here is the repository if you want to see the whole codebase: https://github.com/TRahulSam1997/dostoevsky.rest

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you use the volume definition for web-root like you do, rather than defining the volume mount in the webserver and cert-bot services as `- /root/dostoevskyrest/views/:/var/www/html`? I think your issue is that Docker is trying to find a volume called /root/dostoevskyrest/views/ rather than making a bind mount which is what I think you want.

Comment: @HansKilian You're right. Simple changing the volume mount instead of using web-root worked.